# Periodic Statements in Pennsylvania

Tags: consumer-protection, pennsylvania, new-jersey, lease

I live in PA, car was leased in PA, leasing company is in NJ.

I've never received a statement.  Ever.  Not monthly, not quarterly.  In fact when I called today, I was told "we don't send statements."  Not electronic, and not paper.

Is this common practice and more importantly, legal?

Answer (score 1):

Periodic statements might be required by contract. You don't say if your lease contract specifies or requires statements. If it does, you can probably take legal action to force the company to comply. You may need a lawyer for this.

Statements could also be required by statute, particularly for consumer transactions. This would be a matter of state law. I found some states that required statements for specific kinds of transactions. I found a number of things that a person offering a consumer auto lease in PA must disclose. None of those mentioned periodic statements. There may be some PA statute or regulation requiring statements which i missed. But unless there is, there seems to be no statute in PA requiring such statements.